# IntelliJ 14 on OSX: How to specify version of SVN client used through the IDE

Tags: bash, svn, intellij-idea, oh-my-zsh

I'm on OSX Yosemite which came with a default SVN client 1.7.x.
I used macports to install 1.8.11 and checked out a repo using 1.8.11 (through zshell).
When i use the `svn` command through the shell (both on zshell and bash), it points to 1.8.11.

However in IntelliJ 14, it reluctantly keeps trying to use the 1.7.x client and errors out saying:
 
`SVN: E155021: this client is too old to work with the working copy`.

If I use the `svn` command through IntelliJ's own terminal, I see that it is 1.8.11.
How can I force IntelliJ to use 1.8.11?
Couldn't see a relevant option in the preferences under Subversion.

Comment: This problem is still valid on IntelliJ IDEA 15 and with svn installed from homebrew. But the http://stackoverflow.com/a/27661045/2693875 solution works too. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found one working solution.
All I really had to do is use the full path of `svn` 1.8.11 (ie. `/opt/local/bin/svn`) installed by macports, under Preferences -> Version Control -> Subversion -> Use command line client

Though I still don't understand why it didn't pick this up by default even though the shells did.

[image]

Comment: Should be expanded with one of the answers below, which responses to "why this happens", and "what to do in 100500 cases exactly like this" (and also helps for other tools like homebrew), imho

Answer (score 4):

To fix, use the path that return command `which svn` and replace the configuration on subversion preference on IntelliJ 14.

Fix on OSX 10.11

Answer (score 1):

Intellij cannot read your environment variables, when not started from shell (i think because of the sandbox in which Intellij runs). So it searches for the svn binary under the default path '/usr/bin' even if you expanded your PATH variable with the path to your macport or homebrew installations. Therefore you have to use the full path to your newer svn version from macport.